# How to an API periodically to receive service health status in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, health-check

I have a scenario where I have to call API periodically to receive health status.

what if I use a while use?

```
 while (true)
  {
// API call
   var health = _client.GetHealth(1).Result;
   if (health)
     {
       some other work

     }
   Thread.Sleep(2000);
  }
```

Comment: In general, sleep loops are rarely a good solution. You might want to take a look at some kind of [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: First, this is available out of the box with [Health Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Second, you can't just create a sleep loop or a timer in a controller. Controller instances are created to serve a single request and will eventually be garbage collected. You need a BackgroundService for long running jobs. Finally, `Thread.Sleep` should never be used in a web application. Use `Task.Delay` at least.

Comment: You could use a [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), which is available in .net core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not calling this API in Controller

Comment: @RabnerCasandara in that case you'll have to explain what you actually want. Where are you calling it? And what is the actual question? Why did you ask if this code is OK? (it's not, don't use .Result)

Comment: Please make your intent clear, do you want to report health of your API/service, or you want a client application to periodically report Healths of multiple services you have hosted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already available through the [Health Checks middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks). The health checks service will check the registered probes periodically to see if everything is OK. The health status can be logged or exposed through an API endpoint.

There are several probes available. The open source [AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) library offers probes from everything from remote APIs to various database products, cloud services and more. It also offers a Health check dashboard that displays detailed health check history.

Using Health Checks is easy, as it's already included in the web app templates.

Registering it requires adding the following to `Startup.cs` :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
    });
}
```

`MapHealthChecks` exposes a basic status at `/health` endpoint. To check a remote API you can add the `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris` package and use one of the [AddUrlGroup](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/src/HealthChecks.Uris/DependencyInjection/UrisHealthCheckBuilderExtensions.cs) overloads:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddUrlGroup(new Uri("http://httpbin.org/status/200"));
}
```

Comment: How can I achieve it without Health Check middleware

Comment: @RabnerCasandara why? Why replicate what's already available and just works? What is your actual question? Besides, I already answered in the comments that the only way to perform a job periodically out of the box is to use a BackgroundService

Comment: my GetHealth method is callinga REST endpoint to check that API health

Comment: So does the example I just posted. Your question is getting heavily downvoted because it's unclear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async programming,

```cs
public async Task HealthCheckAsync()
{
 while (true)
  {
// API call
   var health = await _client.GetHealth(1);
   if (health)
     {
       some other work

     }
    await Task.Delay(2000);
  }
}
```

This works the same way except that it is not blocking the main thread while it waits for the response from server or while it is waiting for next cycle.

Comment: This doesn't work for the same reason `Thread.Sleep` doesn't work. Controller actions are only meant for short-lived requests and will be GCd eventually, or throw a timeout. Besides, health checks are built into ASP.NET Core

Comment: I believe he was looking for a health check client. In such cases it works. It doesnt have to be controller action, it can be an independent console app.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, a Monitoring app has to keep polling the health check endpoint in an API,
for the API to run a health check & then get back the health report.

But, now there is a new system called **LiveHealthChecks**.

This auto runs health checks on the API periodically &
the Monitoring apps receive the **health report in real-time**,
via a Server,
**using SignalR push notifications**.

Project site on GitHub: [LiveHealthChecks](https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/LiveHealthChecks)

There is a Server component & a Client one. These are Nuget packages.

- [Server Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Live.Api.HealthChecks.Server)
- [Client Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Live.Api.HealthChecks.Client)

The **Client** one is installed on the API. It periodically runs health checks on the API & sends the report to the Server SignalR hub.

The **Server** one is a stand-alone app, which relays health reports between the API & Monitoring apps.

The **Monitoring apps** are connected to the Server using any SignalR Client & receive the health reports in real-time.

[Live Health Checks Sequence Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg2iw.png)

[Live Health Checks Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBpPX.png)

Monitoring apps hook into the Server very easily using [any SignalR Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/client-features?view=aspnetcore-7.0).
Eg:

```cs
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                        .WithUrl("https://localhost:5001/livehealthcheckshub", o =>
                        {
                            o.Headers.Add("LiveHealthChecks-ReceiveMethod", "*");
                            o.Headers.Add("LiveHealthChecks-SecretKey", "f22f3fd2-687d-48a1-aa2f-f2c9181364eb");
                            //Optional - value can be anything you want. good for tracking in the logs.
                            o.Headers.Add("LiveHealthChecks-ClientId", "Monitoring App 1");
                        })
                        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                        .Build();

connection.On<string>("SampleApiHealth", report =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(report);
});

connection.On<string>("SampleApi2Health", report =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(report);
});

await connection.StartAsync();
```

[**LiveHealthChecks-UI**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxObo.jpg)